# Transformer going into receptacle obstructed by board behind it

Tags: wiring, receptacle, transformer, doorbell

I am in the process of upgrading my doorbell transformer. (I am the fella from yesterday with the question about broken off back stabbed wires, registered with a proper account this time)

In addition to upgrading the transformer I am now changing out the receptacle. Removed the existing receptacle, tried putting the new transformer in and ran into a minor speed bump. The utility box that holds the receptacle is to the bottom right of my panel mounted on particle board. The new transformer secures itself via. threaded clamp going into a hole on the box. The threading on the new transformer can't really get into the hole entirely or straight due to the edge of the particle board blocking it. Here's a photo:

[image]

I have been thinking about what my options are. What I have thought of so far:

1. Keep it as is. It's not pretty but I wound the clamp through a couple thread rotations to the point where it feels secure enough.
2. Move the box right to the edge of the particle board so there is no obstruction.
3. Find a place to screw the transformer right onto the particle board, or add some board next to the particle board and screw the transformer on there if there is no room in current setup.
4. Purchase a different transformer that has the same screw in style as the old one.
5. Completely overhaul and move where my transformer is hooked up.

Option 1 is obviously the laziest but if it's safe would probably be preferred. 2 and 3 are happy mediums and then 4 and 5 are last resorts. At this point I suppose I am looking to get opinions and/or suggestions in case I have missed anything. The other thing is there was another ground wire I had not noticed screwed to the box against the particle board. My plan was to remove that, pigtail the grounds and connect them to the ground screw of the receptacle assuming that is OK? Anyways sorry for the drawn out post and question. First home and have only owned for a couple months, so I am finding a lot of surprises.

Comment: Welcome!  Now that you have enough rep, go back to that other question and write a comment.  Then go to the bottom of the page, left edge, hit "Contact" and ask staff to merge your accounts so your temporary IDs on that other question are converted to this one.

Comment: Thanks! It is saying I need 50 rep to write a comment on that other thread. Should I try reaching out to staff anyways or do they need a comment for the merge?

Comment: Yeah, you could try reaching staff anyway.   Sorry thought it was 25, which I had just bumped you over :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a

[metal box cover with a knockout in it](https://www.lowes.com/pd/RACO-1-Gang-Rectangle-Metal-Electrical-Box-Cover/3128075).

I think you will have enough room to access the screws of the cover. You will need a plug for the knockout on the side.

[image]

Or, the box is surface mounted, add a spacer behind it.

Comment: So with that cover am I basically getting rid of a receptacle there and instead putting the transformer at the front of the box? If that is the case am I still OK to pigtail any existing wires together?

Comment: I did not read closely enough to see it also housed a receptacle. Yes you can eliminate it and make your wire nut connections. You could change it a double gang box to have both. You could move the box away from the wall by putting a board/spacer behind it.

Comment: I will probably try going with a combination of your answer and one of my options. I moved the box close to the edge and the transformer fits in fine now. However, I am going to cap off/connect the existing wires and hold off on putting in a receptacle now, opting for the cover you linked instead. My last question is I noticed 2 of my grounds are connected to the box's ground screw. One was just cut off:

https://i.imgur.com/VsPjPHP.png 

I was just going to keep it as is and only connect the remaining 2 grounds wires I have? If I should post a separate thread for this that's fine. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, indeed.  In fact, those transformers are sold in another form-factor, which is a transformer on the cover of a junction box!!!   OP if you want the recep also, feel free to buy a second handy-box and a [1/2" Rigid conduit box spacer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-2-in-Rigid-Box-Spacer-91641/100144864) to connect them via a knockout.  They also make longer ones with an offset, "offset nipple". Steel boxes and metal conduit go together like an Erector Set!

Comment: Thanks I will definitely pick that up as well, it certainly would be handy to still have the receptacle!

Comment: if you want to keep the outlet use the second option "add a spacer behind the box", you can use any kind on construction wood for that,  a piece of of chipboard or an offcut ot 2x4 etc,